# Facebook API posting on page shows html tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I' m sorry if this is a stupid or already answered question, I could not find anything about this.

I'm automatically posting on facebook from a custom built app in this way:

```
 $params = array(
    "access_token" => $page_token,
    "message" => 'mymessage',
    "link" => 'mylink',
    "name" => 'myname',
    "caption" => 'mycaption',
    "description" => strip_tags($temp_role)
 );
 $ret = $fb->api('/007/feed', 'POST', $params);
```

As you can see I'm stripping tags from the description BUT I see all of them on the actual facebook post `(<p>This is my text <br/> you get the idea</p>)`.

Why is this happening, what am I missing?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What's actually in $params when you go to send it? did strip_tags actually strip the tags?

Comment: Yes it does actually strip the tags, I get the impression that it's picking up the text from the actual shared page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the culprit in a strange issue with character encoding, if anyone else stumbles upon this question this was the solution:

```
strip_tags( html_entity_decode($temp_role) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Description should be the simple text.

just remove the tags.

That's all

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `html tags` in the description, it's not allowed, it must be plain-text.

But if you wish add some extra links to the description, you can use the `properties` parameter just like this:

```
properties={"This SE is best":{text: 'Google', href: 'http://google.com/'}, "This SE is Cool":{text: 'Bing', href: 'http://bing.com/'}}
```

Comment: Did not help at all, not what I asked.